# AWS event bridge rule role not attaching to event bridge when creating via CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-event-bridge, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have a Cloudformation template to create an event bridge rule with target to a central event bus running in another account. When i run the below code , both IAM role and event bridge is getting created but the IAM role is not getting attached to eventbridge rule. Below is the yaml template i am using.

Please see the attached screenshot also.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
    EventRuleRegion1:
        Type: AWS::Events::Rule
        Properties: 
            Description: Event rule to send events to monitoring account event bus
            EventBusName: default
            EventPattern:
                source:
                    - aws.ec2
                    
            Name: ec2-lifecycle-events2
            RoleArn: !GetAtt
                - EventBridgeIAMrole
                - Arn
            State: ENABLED
            Targets: 
                - Arn: >-
                    arn:aws:events:ap-southeast-2:123456789123:event-bus/central-eventbus-sydney
                  Id: 'central-eventbus-sydney'
                  
                  
    
    
    EventBridgeIAMrole:
        Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
        Properties:
            AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
                Version: 2012-10-17
                Statement:
                    - Effect: Allow
                      Principal:
                        Service: !Sub events.amazonaws.com
                      Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
            Path: /
            Policies:
                - PolicyName: PutEventsDestinationBus
                  PolicyDocument:
                    Version: 2012-10-17
                    Statement:
                        - Effect: Allow
                          Action:
                            - 'events:PutEvents'
                          Resource:
                            - >-
                              arn:aws:events:ap-southeast-2:123456789123:event-bus/central-eventbus-sydney
```

[image]

## Manually Created Event rule which shows the role created and attached.

[image]

## Policy in the role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "events:PutEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:events:ap-southeast-2:123456789123:event-bus/central-eventbus-sydney"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: There is no screenshot.

Comment: @Marcin, sorry , missed to attach the screenshot. I have attached it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-account permissions are not set using role, but EventBus resource permissions. From [docs][1]:

> The permissions for an event bus are granted or denied using a **resource-based policy attached to the event bus**.

To do this in CloudFormation, you have to develop your own [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html).

**Update**

You haven't specified [RoleArn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-events-rule-target.html#cfn-events-rule-target-rolearn) for your target. This is different `RoleArn` that you have now.

Comment: Thanks Marcin. I have already provided the resource policy to allow access in the destination account event bus. If i create an event rule in my source account manually it creates a role and attaches to it in the source account itself . Please see the screenshot of the rule which i created manually in the source account.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, i am new to CFT , so trying to understand , are you saying that i need to specify it under the Target as well. Because i have already specified that above the Target i like this.                                                                                                         
             `Name: ec2-lifecycle-events2
            RoleArn: !GetAtt
                - EventBridgeIAMrole
                - Arn
            State: ENABLED`

Comment: @JijoJohn Yes, it must be in Targets. You don't need it in the place you have it now.

Comment: i modified it , but that didn't work Can you please help  `            Targets: 
                - Arn: >-
                    arn:aws:events:ap-southeast-2:123456789123:event-bus/central-eventbus-sydney
                  Id: 'central-eventbus-sydney'
            RoleArn: !GetAtt
                - EventBridgeIAMrole
                - Arn    `

Comment: I have added the role arn under target and it worked. Earlier there was some syntax error due to line spaces. Thanks for your support